# Nintendo 3ds won't connect to my wifi

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds

I can't seem to connect my 3ds in my wifi, but when I connect to other wifis like my friend's house and his pocket wifi it connects. Tried searching in google for solutions nothing work like changing the channel and DNS, resetting the router, changing the password into WEP and removing the password still nothing works. Any solution on how can I solve this?

Comment: What router do you have? Manufacturer, model?

Comment: @AndrewSpartan `TP-LINK` Model: `TL-WR742ND`

Comment: Seems like TP-LINK and Nintendo devices don't like each other. I had problem with TP-LINK and Wii a couple years ago. After a week of struggle I gave up and bought another router (even firmware update didn't help) and everything started to work just fine. Sorry to disappoint you. :/

Comment: Are you using 802.11n?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the router isn't in wireless-N only mode for the 2.4GHz band. (Only band setting available if it's not multiband router)